# how to use Cypress route with query strings

Tags: routes, cypress, fixtures

Im trying to capture a request using Cypress route but for some reason it just isnt working.  There is a query string in the url which may be the reason why it isnt working. How do I capture the request using the cy.route?

```
cy.fixture("timeslots").then((json) => {
      cy.route(
        "GET",
        `${Cypress.env("apiUrl")}availability?startDate*`,
        json
      );
    });
```

Ive tried a ton of different variation on the above but just cant get it working. The actual url is:

```
baseApiUrl/availability?startDate=Thu%2C+02+Jul+2020+13%3A16%3A48+GMT&locationId=55cfb68b-c9b5-ea11-9b05-2818783b5d9b&typeId=a2cfb68b-c9b5-ea11-9b05-2818783b5d9b&isNewCommander=false&timeZone=Mars%2FSolaria
```

Id really appreciate a hand on this

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully this is useful to other but this issue was solved by using a regex instead of the globster.

```
cy.route("GET", new RegExp(/\bavailability\?startDate=\b/), json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering if you initialized `cy.server()` before `cy.fixture("timeslots")...`?
(remember you have to start a server before routing any response to `cy.route()` and to change the behavior of network requests if you need that ;) ).
Also, you have to set up your routes to listen before visiting the application.

Related the query string from the url, you can use any globster to check if it matches and pass, so I believe this glob should work. `**/availability?**`:

```
 cy.server();
 cy.route('GET', '**/availability?**', 'fixture:timeslots');
 cy.visit('/')
```

Comment: thanks for your response but I did use the server first. In the end I had to use a regex to solve the issue.